# How to call functions from a .dll file from java?

Tags: java, c#, .net, dll, leanft

I have a .dll file that was used with HP UFT(vbScript) as an add-in to identify UI objects.
Now we have moved from HP UFT to HP LeanFT(java). Is there any way to call the same .dll file functions through java.

Comment: Are you able to add the dll as a reference to the C# project? If so, it should be pretty straightforward from there.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at JNI wrapper creation for your native DLL: [Java Native Interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface)